# Infer Parameters of LogNormalDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to explore whether Mathematica can help me infer the parameters of a `LogNormalDistribution` from observing the values of some integrals. For example, I construct the integral values by using

```
a1 = 3.9; b1 = .9;
val1 = Integrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[a1, b1], x] x, {x, 0, 40}]
val2 = Integrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[a1, b1], x] x, {x, 40, Infinity}]
(*9.5
64.5*)
```

Then, I try to work backwards from these values to see whether one of the minimizing functions can guess the `a1` and `b1` parameters. Using the `NormalDistribution` (instead of the `LogNormalDistribution`) produces success with `FindMinimum` and trying to reduce sum of squared errors. When I do the same with the `LogNormalDistribution`, however, Mathematica goes into a deep think and nothing happens (actually, I lose patience and abort the calculation). Here is what I try:

```
FindMinimum[
 (val1 - (Integrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[al, be], x] x, {x, 0, 40}]))^2 +
 (val2 - (Integrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[al, be], x] x, {x, 40, Infinity}]))^2
 ,{{al, 3.75}, {be, .8}}]
```

Replacing `Infinity` with a large number helps the `NormalDistribution` equivalent task (in part by avoiding some imaginary values; they need to be `PositiveReals`) but does not seem to make a difference here. Many thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the approach provided by user293787 you can use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) to identify initial estimates for [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f1[a_, b_] = 
  Integrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[a, b], x]*x, {x, 0, 40}, 
   Assumptions -> {b > 0}];

f2[a_, b_] = 
  Integrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[a, b], x]*x, {x, 40, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {b > 0}];

val1 = f1[3.9, 0.9];
val2 = f2[3.9, 0.9];

cplt = ContourPlot[
  {val1 == f1[a, b], val2 == f2[a, b]},
  {a, 2, 4}, {b, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

```
ip = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[cplt]

(* {{3.36488, 1.37043}, {3.90046, 0.899019}} *)
```

Use these points as the initial estimates for `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot[{val1 == f1[a, b], val2 == f2[a, b]},
   {{a, #[[1]]}, {b, #[[2]]}}] & /@ ip

(* {{a -> 3.3677, b -> 1.36916}, {a -> 3.9, b -> 0.9}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a fresh kernel, define with `=` (not with `:=`):

```
f1[a_,b_]=Integrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[a,b],x]*x,{x,0,40},Assumptions->{b>0}]
(* 1/2 E^(a+b^2/2) Erfc[(a+b^2-Log[40])/(Sqrt[2] b)] *)

f2[a_,b_]=Integrate[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[a,b],x]*x,{x,40,Infinity},Assumptions->{b>0}]
(* 1/2 E^(a+b^2/2) (1+Erf[(a+b^2-Log[40])/(Sqrt[2] b)]) *)
```

Your values are

```
val1=f1[3.9,.9]
val2=f2[3.9,.9]
```

You can reconstruct the parameters using (you can also use `FindMinimum`):

```
FindRoot[{val1==f1[a,b],val2==f2[a,b]},{{a,3.75},{b,.8}}]
(* {a->3.3677,b->1.36916} *)

FindRoot[{val1==f1[a,b],val2==f2[a,b]},{{a,3.75},{b,1.0}}]
(* {a->3.9,b->0.9} *)
```

There seem to be (at least) two solutions actually.

Comment: Instead of integrating, we can do `f1[a_, b_] = Expectation[x*Boole[x<40], x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[a,b]]` etc.

Comment: Also note that `val1+val2 = E^(a + b^2/2)` which then requires only one `Integrate` or `Expectation`.  This assumes that the same number (in this case `40`) is used in both integrations.

Comment: @Roman The actual integrals are somewhat more complicated, they are not simple expectations.